# perl6/rakudo: How could I disable autoflush?

Tags: raku, autoflush, rakudo-star

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$*OUT.autoflush( 0 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$*OUT.autoflush = False` should disable it, and it runs without error, but it seems that parrot's IO still flushes automatically. So there currently doesn't seem to be an easy way.

Comment: [2014 updates from the #perl6 log](http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/search/?nick=&q=autoflush) boil down to autoflush being still not implemented in Rakudo at the Perl 6 level. In fact, `$*OUT.autoflush = False` currently gives me a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Rakudo doesn't support autoflush. There's a note in [5to6-perlvar](https://docs.perl6.org/language/5to6-perlvar) under the `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH` entry.

Some examples from a long time ago mention an `autoflush` method, but that has disappeared:

```
$*ERR.autoflush = True;
$*ERR.say: "1. This is an error";
$*OUT.say: "2. This is standard out";
```

But that doesn't work:

> No such method 'autoflush' for invocant of type 'IO::Handle'

I haven't seen any discussions about when this might show up as a feature, or a proclamation that it will never be a feature.